# Problem on symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetry

Let $A$ be square non-singular matrix of order $n \geq 2$.

1. If $A$ is symmetric, then $A^2$ is symmetric positive definite.
2. If $A^2$ is symmetric positive definite, then $A$ is symmetric.

I think I have an idea how to prove (1). Consider $x'A^2x$. If A is symmetric, then $x'A^2x = x'AAx = x'A'Ax = (Ax)'Ax = $ sum of squares that cannot be negative. Hence, $A^2$ is positive semidefinite for sure. Now, given $\det A^2 = ( \det A )^2 \neq 0$, we may conclude that $A^2$ is positive definite (I used the result that states “positive semidefiniteness + non-singularity = positive definiteness”). QED

So, my question is: is my proof correct and how to find a counterexample to (2)?

Comment: Your proof is correct. Why do you think b is wrong?

Comment: I have answers and they says (2) is false, but I falied to come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for 1. is correct. For 2., you can consider an [involution matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222359/is-there-anything-special-about-this-matrix)  like
$$A:=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 1&-1}.$$
We have 
$A^2=3I_2$ but $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: How did you come up with such a matrix?

Comment: @Mirak this is called a involution matrix. See here for yet some other examples:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1222359/191404